# How do I press "Enter chill zone button" on the website version of the discord using selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, discord

I tried everything to make my code click the button but it can't. I tried using xpath, id, class. Neither of them worked. Does anyone have an idea for this to work?

HTML:

```html
  <div data-focus-lock-disabled="false" class="inner-1ilYF7">
    <form class="modal-yWgWj- container-14fypd sizeSmall-1jtLQy fullscreenOnMobile-1aglG_">
        <div class="scrollerWrap-2lJEkd content-1EtbQh scrollerThemed-2oenus themeGhostHairline-DBD-2d">
            <div class="scroller-2FKFPG systemPad-3UxEGl inner-ZyuQk0 content-dfabe7">
                <h2 class="h2-2gWE-o title-3sZWYQ defaultColor-1_ajX0 title-18-Ds0 marginBottom20-32qID7 marginTop8-1DLZ1n">WOAH THERE. WAY TOO SPICY</h2>
                <div class="body-Mj9Oxz medium-zmzTW- primary-jw0I4K">You're sending messages too quickly!</div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="flex-1xMQg5 flex-1O1GKY horizontalReverse-2eTKWD horizontalReverse-3tRjY7 flex-1O1GKY directionRowReverse-m8IjIq justifyBetween-2tTqYu alignStretch-DpGPf3 wrap-ZIn9Iy footer-3rDWdC" style="flex: 0 0 auto;">
                    <button type="submit" class="primaryButton-2BsGPp button-38aScr lookFilled-1Gx00P colorBrand-3pXr91 sizeXlarge-2yFAlZ grow-q77ONN">
                        <div class="contents-18-Yxp">Enter the chill zone</div>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

My code for finding the button looks like this:

```
try
    {
        var element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[text()='Enter the chill zone']"));

        if (element.Displayed)
        {
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/form/div[2]/button")).Click();
            Console.WriteLine("Button clicked!");
        }
    }
catch (Exception e)
{
     Console.WriteLine(e);
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the html of the button.

Comment: Check if the element is present in the iframe?

Comment: Is the button you are trying to click the parent BUTTON in the HTML you provided? The one that contains the DIV with the "Enter the chill zone" text?

Comment: check the html now

Comment: @bial654321 the iframe could be more global than just one div tag.
Try to search <iframe> or <frameset> tags on the whole entire DOM structure of this particular page.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reach the element by type attribute. Like this:

```
"//button[@type='submit']"
```

Comment: The thing is I get an error about program not finding the text box (the one in which program should write in characters) because the button overlays it 

```Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.122)```

Comment: Looks like this element is inside frame.
Please check whether your element is located inside <iframe> or smth like that.
Or better provide the full UI of page and full DOM structure

Comment: check the html now

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so to locate/`click()` on the element you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("button[type='submit'] div[class^='contents']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//button[@type='submit']/div[starts-with(@class,'contents') and text()='Enter the chill zone']"))).Click();
  ```